# Adding Wordpress categories to database, changes only show after update via interface

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, caching, categories

I'm injecting Wordpress categories into my MySQL database. This is fine when it comes to categories without a parent. But when I add a child category it doesn't show in the Wordpress category list.

I believe this has something to do with Wordpress caching the query or the results for the category tree. I have tried to use this function to force Wordpress to clean the cache:

```
clean_term_cache( $ids, $taxonomy, $clean_taxonomy );
```

Found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/clean_term_cache

Unfortunately it still only shows my changes after I edit and save one of the visible categories.

So to be clear: The things I do in the database work. I add the records to the right tables. The only problem is that the Wordpress admin interface doesn't show the changes. Until I use said interface to edit / save a category that IS visible in the admin interface.

Also: I use direct database injection because I'm using WooCommerce + WPML. The API's don't support creating multi-lingual categories.

Comment: `clean_term_cache()` is the function to use for this. Can you confirm the arguments you're using?  Specifically, `$clean_taxonomy` should almost always be `true` when creating child categories.

Comment: Right now I'm keeping track of all the ids of the categories I create. That's the array I use as the first parameter. The taxonomy is 'product_cat' and from what I understand is $clean_taxonomy true by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was due to the fact that I was trying to recursively add categories and translate them. I had to add a category to the database with one translation and add the other translations afterwards. But whenever I ran the functions to clear the cache, WPML also went to work. This messed up the whole translation.

I ended up creating a category myself and immediately deleting it after running all of my code. This seemed to work.

It hurts my programmer heart to share this, but this is how I fixed my problem. So here goes:

```
$temp_term = wp_insert_term('Fake category', 'product_cat', ['description' => 'Temporary category', 'slug' => 'fake-cat-temp']);
wp_delete_term($temp_term['term_id'], 'product_cat');
```